# grep regex multiple replacements

Tags: regex, search, grep, expression

I will probably have done it "manually" by the time I get an answer for this.

I have two variables (varA, varB) I want to replace with (a, b) respectively, this currently requires two separate find and replaces.

with regex grep I know how to do two separate searches using
    varA | varB

but there is no replace function that will similarly do a respective replacement

unless you know better? thanks for any insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep is used for searching pattern in a given input. You should use sed for text replacements. For multiple replacements in single sed command just use it like this:

```
sed -e 's/varA/foo/g' -e 's/varB/bar/g' file.txt
```

Comment: excellent thanks! just ran it from the command line. I had been use textwrangler's "grep" option to input regular expressions

Comment: Glad that you found it useful :)